# считывание массива из потока

Tags: c++, массивы, потоки-данных, шаблоны-с++

Нужно перегрузить оператор считывания из потока для шаблонного класса. В шаблонном классе Set есть поле - массив элементов другого шаблонного класса Point:

```
class Set
{
public:

    Set()
    {
        _ptr = nullptr;
        _capacity = 0;
        _size = 0;
    }

    Set(int capacity)
    {
        _ptr = new classType[capacity];
        _capacity = capacity;
        _size = 0;
    }
    template<class classType>
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Set<classType>& set);

    template <class classType>
    friend istream& operator >> (istream &stream, Set<classType>& set);
}

class Point
{
public:

    Point()
    {
        _x = 0;
        _y = 0;
        _z = 0;
    }

    Point(T x, T y, T z)
    {
        _x = x;
        _y = y;
        _z = z;
    }
    template<typename T>
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Point<T>& p);

    template<typename T>
    friend istream& operator >> (istream &stream, Point<T>& p);
}
```

сама реализация:

```
    template <class classType>
istream &operator >> (istream &stream, Set<classType>& set)
{
    cout << "Enter capacity: ";
    stream >> set._capacity;
    cout << "Enter size: ";
    stream >> set._size;

    cout << "Enter elements: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < set._size; ++i)
        stream >> set._ptr[i];
    return stream;
}

template <typename T>
istream &operator >> (istream &stream, Point<T>& p)
{
    stream >> p._x >> p._y >> p._z;
    return stream;
}
```

происходит вылет из gtest-ов после считывания capacity b size и начала считывания первого элемента из _ptr (_ptr[0])

скриншот тестов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, что делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как минимум у вас УЖЕ есть `Set`, в который вы считываете. С выделенной памятью (боюсь, нулевой - если вы создали его без параметра).

При чтении вы просто перезаписываете поля `_capacity` и `_size`, тем самым уже нарушая внутреннее состояние объекта - он-то считает, что у него выделена память для `_capacity` элементов и записано `_size` элементов. Но вы уже нарушили согласованность объекта.

А потом еще и начинаете записывать в память данные. Вы уверены, что `_ptr` указывает на достаточное количество выделенной памяти? Особенно если перед вызовом объявили просто `Set<Type> set;`?

Ситуация понятна?

Comment: не совсем, то есть, мне нужно сначала считать отдельно размер, присвоить его Set._size-у, и потом уже в цикле с for считывать элементы?

Comment: По-хорошему, старую память освободить, новую выделить в соответствии с указанной емкостью. И все это лучше делать не "через голову" вашего класса, а с использованием соответствующего интерфейса - должен же быть у вас код добавления элемента? (вы так порезали представленный код, что у вас даже не очевидно, что `Set` - это шаблон...)

Comment: точно, я понял Вас, сделал так, чтобы удалялся старый _ptr и заводился новый нового размера. А дальше всё идет. Спасибо большое!